# Autoscroll to particular row which were selected previously asp.net core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core

How do I achieve autoscroll in asp.net core?

Below is the scenario,

I have a page which display data in the form of rows, after selecting particular record it takes to view page.
On view page when user click on back button it should take to previous page and should go back to the exact place we were.
I am able to achieve to go back to previous page but challenge is, it should autoscroll to particular record.
Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: You can use HTML anchors to position the scroll in the right place and keep in session storage information about the selected record for when navigating back activate the correct anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maintained for each row a unique Id and used it to be identified by scroller.

```
<tr id="@model.Id">
</tr>
```

Javascript code

```
window.onload = function () {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const empId = urlParams.get('empId');
        if (empId== null || empId== undefined)
            return;
        
        scrollToPreviouslySelectedEmployee(empId);
    }

    function scrollToPreviouslySelectedEmployee(empId) {
        var elmnt = document.getElementById("" + empId);
        elmnt.scrollIntoView();
        elmnt.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
```